# copy failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp64\www\

Tags: php

Im getting these errors

> Warning: copy(http://169.239.217.19/form/UpLoadedFiles/1111.docx):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\
>
> Warning: copy(http://169.239.217.19/form/UpLoadedFiles/MIE Form
>   2016.pdf):failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\wamp64\www\

My code

```
  $serverdir = "http://169.239.217.19/form/UpLoadedFiles/";

    if (!file_exists($serverdir)) {
       mkdir($serverdir, 0775);
    }
               if (copy($serverdir.$file, $serverdir.$file)){
                    echo " <br> Files Copyed Successfully";
                    echo ": <br> ".$serverdir.$file; 
                    //if files you are moving are images you can print it from 
                    //new folder to be sure they are there 
                 }
```

Comment: How should that work? I don't think that `copy` works when using HTTP as the target

Comment: Is that file on the same server than your web server?

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to try and "copy" to a URL. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to copy files on the server but not move them from the local folder